# Maps v2 API Key on Android

Tags: android, keytool

I went to https://code.google.com/apis/console/

I then did this:

```
keytool -v -list -alias ks_ms_ad -keystore W:\eclipse-android-sign\keystore\exampleproject
```

I converted the output

```
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: HH HH HH HH HH HH HH HH   HH HH HH HH HH HH HH H  /x<s7.@...B.).8.
0010: HH HH HH HH                                        .. .
]
]
```

to

```
HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH;com.exampledomain.exampleproject
```

Google actually accepted this, so somehow I turned gibberish into something usable. The "HH" entries matched up with the example given in Google's API console site, so there is a small chance what I did was actually correct.

But above does not seem like how I read it should be? Am I really supposed to do the editing I did? I thought I would get a ready to use md5 from keytool?

I am getting a blank screen witgh zoom buttons [+] [-] which is partly why I think there may be a problem?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: The resulting output I got from keytool.exe looks like gibberrish to me, e.g. the "/x<s7.@...B.).8." part?

Comment: I thought it was a relative simple and relevant questions if other persons usage of keytool gave the same ottuput as mine. The reason I also ask of course is that I can't get any maps demos working :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seem the cause was I had messed up. (You find SHA1 etc. above what I referenced) So just for  for others messing around with this:

**debug keytool fingerprint example:**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\%your name%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH;com.company.product
```

**release keytool fingerprint example:**

```
keytool -v -list -alias youralias -keystore W:\keystore\product
HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH;com.company.product
```

All above can then share the same API key which will have pattern:

```
a-zA-Z0-9-
```

You can get the API key here:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

And find keytool.exe here (example)
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

Answer (score 1):

I think there was an issue with your key itself in the way it has been signed. The fingerPrint seems odd. Pls. check the SHA1 fingerPrint.
Ohk. looks like you have found the issue.